# Ran out of space of newly installed HDD?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, samba

[image]Hi  i just installed a new 6tb hdd and began transfering some files over from my windows 10 machine to my ubuntu server 18.04 with the new 6tb drive partitioned and formated as ext4.

upon transfering almost around 100GB of data, i can no longer transfer anymore as it is saying i have ran out of space!!!

You can see from `df -h` that i am only using 3%...

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           765M  4.0M  761M   1% /run
/dev/sdd2       908G  780G   83G  91% /
tmpfs           3.8G   16K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/loop1      218M  218M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/16402
/dev/loop3       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop2      212M  212M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/16739
/dev/sdb        5.5T  145G  5.0T   3% /media/wd_6tb_pics_2019
/dev/sdc        5.5T  1.5T  3.7T  29% /media/wb6tbOwncloud
/dev/sde1       932G  923G  9.0G 100% /media/WD_1TB_pictures
/dev/sdd1       511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdf2       1.9T  1.7T  154G  92% /media/WD_2tb_9VJN
tmpfs           765M     0  765M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Here is more details of the hdd using the lsblk -o command

```
sdb    ext4       5.5T /media/wd_6tb_pics_2019 Pictures_2019            a3ae30ee-efd1-4a03-b382-da322fb6c30f WD-WX31D47CECD4
```

I am using samba file share and the config part of sharing the root folder for where all my attached devices are is below:

```
    [All_media_drives]
path = /media
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

edit: my fstab entry

```
UUID=a3ae30ee-efd1-4a03-b382-da322fb6c30f   /media/wd_6tb_pics_2019    ext4     defaults,rw   0  2


df-i


Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev              970040    574    969466    1% /dev
tmpfs             978788   1045    977743    1% /run
/dev/sdd2       60514304 335251  60179053    1% /
tmpfs             978788      4    978784    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             978788      4    978784    1% /run/lock
tmpfs             978788     18    978770    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         12842  12842         0  100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/loop1         20782  20782         0  100% /snap/nextcloud/16402
/dev/loop3         12829  12829         0  100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop2         20785  20785         0  100% /snap/nextcloud/16739
/dev/sdb       183144448   2917 183141531    1% /media/wd_6tb_pics_2019
/dev/sdc       183144448 993063 182151385    1% /media/wb6tbOwncloud
/dev/sde1        9623780 158730   9465050    2% /media/WD_1TB_pictures
/dev/sdd1              0      0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sdf2      160873192  71178 160802014    1% /media/WD_2tb_9VJN
tmpfs             978788     11    978777    1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have shared `/media`, which is on `/` file system. You have 83GiB free there. Is what you're copying around 120GiB in size? If so, the error message makes perfect sense.

When Windows asks for the free space of the share, Samba dutifully reports what's free for `/media`, which is the root of the share. Windows checks this, and sees that free space is less than size of objects.

A workaround would be to share each drive as an individual share. It appears that [this is also known behavior](https://github.com/int128/samba-dfree):

> Samba daemon does not report correct disk space if the exported path consists from several disks.
>
> For example, it assumes /home is exported on Samba and consists from 3 disks as follows. Samba daemon should report free space of 210GB but actually reports 10GB.

So it seems that this is a known problem with Samba. Easiest workaround is probably to share each drive as its own share. Another workaround would be install [samba-dfree](https://github.com/int128/samba-dfree)